# How to wait all tasks when calling methods include UI interaction?

Tags: c#, winforms, task

First, I know that there is `WaitAll` and the non-blocking `WhenAll`. My current problem is slightly different but hopefully I might be able to use one of these methods.

So, I have a form that loads a large and complex object from an external WebApi. The loading is done in chunks as follows:

```
public void LoadObject()
{
    LoadChunk1();
    LoadChunk2();
    LoadChunk3();
    LoadChunk4();
    LoadChunk5();
}  

public async void LoadChunk1()
{
    //Clear controls, data bindings etc...

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        chunk = someService.LoadChunk1();
    });

    //Update controls, data bindings etc...
}
```

The exact same applies to all methods. This is all working fine. Now I need to add a progressbar in the main load method so that the user knows when everything is loaded. Also, these methods might be called often from other places in the form and not necessarily from the main method.

Loading synchronously is not an option as the UI blocks for a few seconds so everything has to stay as is.

Is there a way to use `WhenAll` on a task array? Or is it impossible in this case because I access the UI? What if I use `BeginInvoke`?

Comment: _Is there a way to use WhenAll on a task array_ - Yes it is `await Task.WhenAll(LoadChunk1(), LoadChunk2())`

Comment: It would be quicker to type `Task.` and let intellisense help you with all of the methods than to ask a question here.

Comment: Also, your methods should be `async Task LoadChunk1()` and not `async void LoadChunk1()`.

Comment: If you loading data from WebAPi don't use extra threads, use asynchronous methods to load data and await for them.

Comment: Do you need to run these methods in parallel (possibly concurrently) or one after the other? -- As mentioned, it's *mandatory* that your async method(s) is/are of type Task, when no value is returned, not `void` (you cannot await `void`). You can add your Tasks to a `List<Task>`, then run and await one after the other or `await Task.WhenAll([Your List of Tasks])` to run them *in parallel*. If you run and await your Tasks from the UI Thread, the SynchronizationContext is captured without problems, in case you need to update a ProgressBar, eventually.

Comment: If you use `Task.Run()`, you can pass an `IProgress<T>` delegate to the method, which can then report its progress calling back to the UI Thread using the `Progress<T>` delegate's `Report()` method.

Comment: @Enigmativity @Jimi Thanks for the suggestions. Changed `void` to `Task`, and then used `await Task.WhenAll(..)`. Works like a charm!

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono - There can be only one `@` notification per message. If you want Jimi to see the notification you need to do two comments. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The way I approach this problem is to make any method that reports progress take a Progress object. These objects can either contain a: a counter (double) or b: a list of progress objects. This allows the method to either just increment the counter, or split the object into several and give each sub-progress to different methods. The progress object would have method to calculate the total progress of the entire tree.

So your example would look something like this:

```
public void LoadObject(Progress progress)
{
    var subProgress = progress.Split(5)
    LoadChunk1(subProgress[0] );
    LoadChunk2(subProgress[1]);
    LoadChunk3(subProgress[2]);
    LoadChunk4(subProgress[3]);
    LoadChunk5(subProgress[4]);
}  

public async void LoadChunk1(Progress progress)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        chunk = someService.LoadChunk1();
        progress.Value = 1; // This chunk is complete
    });
    
}
```

Combine this with a separate poller that runs on the main thread, checks the overall progress every 0.2s or so, and updates the progress bar. This allow processing to be done in any order, and you can report progress from any thread.

If you have a modal progress dialog you could use `WhenAll` to produce a task that completes when all chunks are loaded, and close the dialog when the task completes.